# How to calculate the resistor value necessary for the columns 8x8 led matrix?

Tags: resistors, ohms-law, led-matrix, calculation

I am building an 8x8 led matrix using 5mm LEDs (3.2V, 20mA). I connect it to the arduino UNO through the I2C using the GPIO expander MCP23017. The circuit is as follows:

[image]

A matrix column is made up of 8 LEDs connected in series (am I right? are they not in series?). The forward current of an Led is 20mA and its forward voltage is 3.2V. I connect the VDD pin of the MCP23017 to the 5V pin of the arduino uno.

So, the resistor value I need to connect to a column so that the LEDs don't die out is (5V-(3.2V*8))/0.02, which is a negative value! Shouldn't I multiply 3.2V by 8? if not, why?

Comment: See if http://lednique.com/display-technology/multiplexed-display/ helps regarding whether they're in series or not. (They're not.)

Comment: something is wrong ... the leds appear to have three terminals ... two of the terminals are shorted for some reason

Comment: @jsotola if you're talking about the blue lines, I've just realized I didn't draw them correctly. The anodes of the leds of one column are wired in series (column wise), and the cathodes of the leds of one row are wired in series (row wise)

Comment: that description is unclear ... google `led matrix schematic`

Comment: You should draw a proper, correct schematic and delete the existing one.

Comment: What peak current are you planning if\$ I_{f_{max}}=30 mA\$ and 30/8 =3.75 mA?

Comment: @S.E.K. If muxing, the usual arrangement is to get yourself a nice low-side current-limiting driver IC with 8 current sinks and do high-side switching using 8 external driver circuits to handle the possible dissipation of driving up to 8 LEDs at full (over-full, because of the muxing going on) at one time.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 according to the datasheet of the MCP23017,the maximum output current sourced by any output pin is 25mA, So the max current that can go through an led is 25mA. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is Common Anode Mux with fixed V and Cathode current limited somehow either CC or using an R.

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but I honestly have no idea what you're talking about, my electronics knowledge is very limited. Could you suggest links to tutorials or articles that explain the notions you're suggesting in your answer, or at least names of laws-components-principles I can investigate?

Comment: I have nothing handier than you with the web search engine and my key words with an LED matrix design  https://tinyurl.com/ygvmj67f